# Filter view based on displayed part of an Open Layers map

Tags: views, location, javascript

I have a page that shows an OpenLayers map which is fed with data coming from an Open Layers data overlay view (user locations; the location is provided via a location cck field in the user account settings). Right underneath the map the overlay data is listed using a clone of the Open Layers data overlay.

Is there a way to filter the displayed entitites in the list based on what part of the map is currently looked at? That is, is there a way to hide entities from the list when I zoom into a different part of the map?

Example: Zoomed to full extend, showing the whole world -> display all entities. Zoomed to the US, showing only California -> display all entities with a Californian location.

Answer (score 2):

We had the same requirement in a recent project. It was solved with javascript, there is no out of the box way to do this.

Please see https://www.transpower.co.nz/projects

Here is some code to get you started:

```
(function ($, Drupal, window, document, undefined) {

  // ...

  $(function(){

    if($(".not-front .openlayers-map").length && !$('.node-type-project').length) { // only run when there is actually a map on the page, but not on the home page

      if ($('body').hasClass('page-community-initiatives')) {
        is_ci = true;
      }

      mapData = $(".openlayers-map").data('openlayers').openlayers;
      pointLayers = mapData.getLayersByClass("OpenLayers.Layer.Vector");

      // cycle through all layers and points on those layers, adding the points to an array
      for (var i in pointLayers) {
        for (var j in pointLayers[i].features) {
          pointData.push(pointLayers[i].features[j]);
        }
      }

      // if we've pulled out some points, go make a list
      if (pointData.length) {
        makeList(pointData, ".pane-openlayers-map");
      } else {
        $('.pane-openlayers-map').append('<div class="no-results"><p>Your search returned no results, please try again.</p></div>')
      }

      // add event listener to the map to be fired whenever the user interacts with it.
      // calls refreshList function above
      mapData.events.on({
        "moveend": refreshList
      });

      Drupal.openlayers.popup.popupSelect.events.on({
        "featurehighlighted": popupOpen,
        "featureunhighlighted": popupClose
      });

    }

  });

})(jQuery, Drupal, this, this.document);
```

The entire JS file can be download (unminified) from the [theme](https://www.transpower.co.nz/sites/all/themes/transpower/js/search.js). Please alter to suit your needs.